# How do I change the ::before content of an element based on a class that is added via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

What I am trying to do is change the content of a button when I add a class to the button.

I have a pen that shows exactly what I mean:

app.js

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', toggleClickedClass);

function toggleClickedClass() {
  this.classList.toggle('clicked');
}
```

style.scss

```
button.toggle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #ff2356;

  &::before {
    content: "Click Me";
  }

  .clicked::before {
    content: "How dare you!";
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<div class="container">
  <button class="toggle"></button>
</div>
```

Here's a codepen showing what I mean: http://codepen.io/khall47/pen/oBeOdY

What I expect:

The button should say "How dare you!" when the 'clicked' class is present on the button and 'Click Me' when the 'clicked' class is absent.

What I get:

The button says 'Click Me' all the time, whether or not the 'clicked' class has been added to it.

I've looked at articles on CSS-Tricks and MDN, and I haven't seen anything like this mentioned.  How would I make this work?

Comment: I think you're just missing the ampersand before your clicked selector. `&.clicked::before`

Comment: Yep, that did it. Please add as answer, and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example produces this;

```
button.toggle .clicked::before
```

But this is what you are looking for;

```
button.toggle.clicked::before
```

You're missing an ampersand

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', toggleClickedClass);

function toggleClickedClass() {
  this.classList.toggle('clicked');
}
```

```css
button.toggle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #ff2356;
  &::before {
    content: "Click Me";
  }
  &.clicked::before {
    content: "How dare you!";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="toggle"></button>
</div>
```